# How to establish connections to a ServerSocket from internet?

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

My `ServerSocket` listens to LAN Connections and accepts them well, but when I try to connect to the same through my Phone - using the 3G connection - it doesn't seem to connect.

1. I tried using `getMyIP` site to get the `IP` and try to connect to it, it does get the right `IP` (checked with my router) but then no connections are accepted at all.
2. I tried opening the port on windows 7 and on my router altogether.
3. I put those lines in my Server constructor:

   ```
   ss = new ServerSocket(port);
   host=ss.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();
   ```

   and I get the ip on host to 0.0.0.0

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is the machine where the `ServerSocket` is run, behind a firewall?

Comment: only windows7's firewall

Comment: In order to connect to your machine from internet, you should have a public IP, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a public IP address.  If you have a router it must pass traffic for the port you want to expose to the internet to your machine. If you have a firewall, it must allow external connections to this port.

All the changes you do are the same regardless of language you use and there is nothing you can do from Java to work around needing to do these things.

Comment: Peter, IMO problem the OP is facing the binding the socket to the IP address which is allocated by OPs ISP. By default its `0.0.0.0`. It needs and explicit binding.

Comment: When you bind to `0.0.0.0` it binds to everything.  You are still bound, you just don't know to what.

Comment: Any active interface regardless of IP address.

Answer (score 2):

**-** While you are at `LAN`, you can use the `Private IP` as well as `Public IP ranges`

**-** But when you are using the `Internet` to access the Server which is at your place, then you **need to have a** `static Public IP address.`

**-** You can ask for a `static Public IP address` from your ISP at some extra cost, there are also some site over net that some how provides a static IP on the basis of your Dynamic IP.

**Private IP ranges Can't be used over the Internet.**

```
Class A - 10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255  

Class B - 172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255

Class C - 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255
```

Comment: but still, why do i get 0.0.0.0 from that socketserver? and how do i change my code so that the serversocket would host on a public IP rather then on this 0.0.0.0 ip?

Comment: @OfekRon you need to have a static Public IP to host your ServerSocket at that IP on some Port nos....... Your ServerSocket is not able to get an IP,

Comment: I tried to use my Router's IP as it is being provided by the WhatsMyIP site, this is surely not a private IP and yet it didnt work... plz give me a little more detailed instructions cause im really confused

Comment: @OfekRon 0.0.0.0, in this context, means "all IP addresses on the local machine" . So, if your webserver machine has two ip addresses, 192.168.1.1 and 10.1.2.1, and you allow a webserver daemon like apache to listen on 0.0.0.0, it will be reachable at both of those IPs. But only to what can contact those IPs and the web port(s). But you still need a static Public IP 

Note that, in a different context (routing) 0.0.0.0 usually means the default route (the route to "the rest of" the internet, aside from routes in your local network etc.).

Comment: @OfekRon you need a static Public IP.... static, that hows that server is reachable at any moment of time

Comment: @OfekRon I already mentioned that in my answer..but still.... you need to pay a little extra for that to ur ISP, or there are some site over the net, that somehow convert ur dynamic ip to static ip

Comment: well I have been given a static IP address by the ISP long time ago, but how do i actually get the value of it, and how do i get serversocket to bind to it?

Comment: First be confirmed that you do have a Static Public IP... see this again STATIC AND PUBLIC are the words. then you can simply do what you do to initialize a ServerSocket, keep the Port nos higher than 1024..... and Please disable any firewall in between. or provide a exception in firewall

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your firewall if it allows incoming connection. You need to make and exception there.
2. you need to bind explicitly the IP address on your machine which is allocated for that instance of time by your ISP.
3. You can get the IP address allocated to you by running `ipconfig` command on windows command prompt.
4. Use the following code to bind to a specific IP address

   ```
   InetSocketAddress insa = new InetSocketAddress("22.23.23.111", 9090);       
   ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket();
   ss.bind(insa);
   String host=ss.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();
   System.out.println(host);
   ```

This prints the IP address allocated to you.